# android listview getting the position of the view

Tags: android, listview

In the getview of my listview i am assigning the position to another variable .
I have a checkbox within my listrow.

I have defined setOnCheckedChangeListener for checkbox.

Now when i jus check / uncheck row , i see that the getview is not getting called.
But i use the value of position which is set in getview and its giving me the right value.

ie if i click 10th position , the variable is also having 10 .

Please explain me how is this working.

My code is below

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        final int pos = position;
        barcodeForSelectedRow = productList.get(pos).getBarcode();
        formatForSelectedRow = productList.get(pos).getFormat();
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_row, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productid);

            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.text2.setOnClickListener(listener);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.productimageid);
            holder.check=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.image.setOnClickListener(listener);

    } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        // setWishListItemsInScanList(pos, convertView);
        holder.check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkBox,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("CheckBox check", "" + pos);


        });
        return convertView;
    }
```

Here i am setting pos= position within getview
When i click checkbox of row 10, the oncheckchnaged listener is getting invoked, but not the getview function
but i see its position is getting correctly in onchechchangedlistener .
I wnat to know how its happening

NB : getview is called whenever i come to this activity, which is the expected behaviour, Also when i click a checkbox getview shouldnt be called, and it is also working fine. My question is how oncheckchangedlistener gets position value correctly

Comment: You should extract the relevant parts instead of posting all this code. In the process, you might find the solution...

Comment: You mean,your control doesn't go into onCheckedChange() of check box?

Comment: onCheckedChanged this function will be called when u change the status of the check box. Not your getView method

Comment: yes , thats right but how is the value coming right

Comment: i have updated my question. hope its more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getView() is called for each particular view, so each time you set the setOnCheckedChangeListener() you pass the local value "pos". Each time getview() is called, a new variable "pos" is created and because you set it final it couldn't be any other way. So each setOnCheckedChangeListener() has it's own instance of the "pos" variable.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean getview is not being called? Be careful with using position from getview. If you scroll position will be recycled, as well if you onresume.

**EDIT**
The short answer to your comment would be list.getPositionInView(View view);

Comment: i dont think the position is recycled, the convert view will be recycled for each view group . But position will not change on scroll, because usually position is used to get the content from data array / list

Comment: What do you mean your getview function is not being called? If it's not being called shouldn't even load the activity, at most you would get an empty activity. If your view is not scrollable there will be no issue while on the activity of the position being correct. If thats the case, onpause the activity (hit home) then go back to the activity from your icon and check your positions. You'll probably find that your position are in opposite order, or that you only have half the positions and each one is being called twice. getpositioninview() will give you more reliability.

Comment: getview is called whenever i come to this activity, which is the expected behaviour, Also when i click a checkbox getview shouldnt be called, and it is also working fine. My question is how oncheckchangedlistener gets position value correctly. Also my view scrollable