# Get position of ListView

Tags: android, performance

I am using Customized listview with editText and checkbox. I displayed both editext and checkbox in

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

and my list view have number of counts presents. The position from getView only shows the number of counts appear in the screen, when i scrolled down, again the position get started from zero. Also i tried list view onItemClick listener, but there is noting response. Is there any way to get the position of listview.

Comment: So, you want the position of the item in the `ListView` ?

Comment: Yes, but i used listview setOnItemClickListener, but this method is not called.

Comment: you can use `setOnItemClickListener`. and use `getItemAtPosition (int position)` to get the item clicked.

position of listview? unclear to me!

Comment: If you have a button or a focusable view in your list item than setOnItemClickListener() will not be called

Comment: Maybe, you should try to get the position inside of the `OnItemClickListener`

Comment: @ Marci Căşvan yes editText is there in my listview.

Comment: So what you want is what?

Comment: I want to get the position of customized list view which is having editeText

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480422/android-listview-getting-the-position-of-the-view?rq=1 refer this ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

 {

     System.out.println("Index:"+position);
      .........
 }
```

`